# How to sum only column with differents values in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to sum column with different values. On this picture I retrieve twice the same LineItem (1), but in SSRS I would like to sum only column like "facturé" which contains differents values and take only values in the other columns.

[image: https://imgur.com/gallery/43fCdd2]

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderNumber
         ,od.odKey
      ,o.oKey
         ,LineItem
         ,`sd.SchedID` AS Sélection
       ,`Quantity` AS Sélectionné
       ,ReleaseDate AS Date_Selection
      ,`Quantity` AS Commandé
         ,CreateDate AS Date_Commande
      ,`CompleteQuantity` AS Produit
         ,CompleteDate As CompleteDate
         ,ShipDate AS ShipDate
         ,ShipQty AS Livré
         ,`Quantity` AS Facturé
         ,Quantity AS Emballé
         ,Date  AS Date_facturation
        ,InvoiceNumber

FROM `tbl1` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl2`  ON `tbl1.oKey` =`tbl2.oKey`
LEFT JOIN `tbl3` ON `tbl2.odKey` = `tbl3.odKey`
LEFT JOIN `tbl4` ON `tbl3.odKey` = `tbl4.odKey`
LEFT JOIN `tbl5` ON `tbl4.InvoiceNumber` = `tbl5.InvoiceNumber`
LEFT JOIN `tbl6`  ON `tbl2.odKey` = `tbl6.odKey`
LEFT JOIN `tbl7` ON `tbl3.oKey` = `tbl7.oKey` 
WHERE OrderNumber = `C100083` --AND (`tbl4.Date` >=`ShipDate` OR `tbl4.Date` IS NULL )
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? The quote character for SQL Server is brackets (`[]`); MySQL uses backticks (`\` `)

Comment: Yes I'm using SQL server, my problem is how to sum in SSRS, I used a wrong quote character

Comment: If you need to sum in SSRS, use the appropriately named function `Sum`. [Sum Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-sum-function?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: In SSRS, add a `Parent Group` to your `Detail`, then add a `SubTotal` for the `Group`. This should automatically add the total values into the subtotal line for each numeric value. Remove the totals you don't want.

Comment: Yes that what I used but it sum all colum, for exemple I'll get 88 for 'Selectionné', 'Livré', 'Emballé' and 90 for 'Produit' 'Selectionné' or I would like to get 44 for 'Selectionné' , 'Livré', 'Emballé' and 'facturé'  and 46 for 'Produit' and 'Selectionné'.

Comment: Remove the sum totals you don't want, keep the ones you do want.

Comment: In this case it will work but there are some cases where I'll need to sum the column i deleted. Like on this picture https://imgur.com/a/eBxOsyE

Comment: When you select columns in your total lines, it will automatically put in the `sum()` function for you, but you should learn how to add the expression yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do is get a distinct list of rows and then sum the value of the column LineItem. To do this you can use a CTE to get a distinct set of rows and then sum the total of lineitem:

```
with cte1 as (SELECT DISTINCT OrderNumber
         ,od.odKey
      ,o.oKey
         ,LineItem
         ,`sd.SchedID` AS Sélection
       ,`Quantity` AS Sélectionné
       ,ReleaseDate AS Date_Selection
      ,`Quantity` AS Commandé
         ,CreateDate AS Date_Commande
      ,`CompleteQuantity` AS Produit
         ,CompleteDate As CompleteDate
         ,ShipDate AS ShipDate
         ,ShipQty AS Livré
         ,`Quantity` AS Facturé
         ,Quantity AS Emballé
         ,Date  AS Date_facturation
        ,InvoiceNumber

FROM `tbl1` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl2`  ON `tbl1.oKey` =`tbl2.oKey`
LEFT JOIN `tbl3` ON `tbl2.odKey` = `tbl3.odKey`
LEFT JOIN `tbl4` ON `tbl3.odKey` = `tbl4.odKey`
LEFT JOIN `tbl5` ON `tbl4.InvoiceNumber` = `tbl5.InvoiceNumber`
LEFT JOIN `tbl6`  ON `tbl2.odKey` = `tbl6.odKey`
LEFT JOIN `tbl7` ON `tbl3.oKey` = `tbl7.oKey` 
WHERE OrderNumber = `C100083`)
select top (1) sum (LineItem1) from cte1;
```

Comment: No I don't want to sum the LineItem column but the others quantity column. I succeded normally, but there are some case where the lineitem repeat such as I got 3 times lineitem (3) or (1). And in these cases, I would like to sum the column where the values are different. When you look at the picture I sent you see that in 'facturé', values are differents and in the other, there are the same for lineitem : 1